# .htaccess redirect directly from a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

There are many questions like this, but I can’t find a solution for this exactly.

I open `example.com/smth1/smth2/media_files`. I want to put a `.htaccess` file in the `media_files` directory which will redirect all links to `example.com/smth1/smth2/new_media_files`.

Note that `smth1`, etc. are dynamic, so I can’t enter them hard coded in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `subdir/.htaccess` you can have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(media_files)(/.*)?$ /$1$2 [L,NC]
```

If you want URLs to change in browser then use `R`  (redirect) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(media_files)(/.*)?$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

---

**EDIT**

As per edited question you can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/media_files(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/new_media_files%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: and how can i rewrite into the same domain subfolder? i.e. i want the content of `media_files` to be redirected into sibling folder,named `new_media_files`

Comment: Then use: `RewriteRule ^media_files(/.*)?$ /new_media_files$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Many thanks. Last question:
if the url is: `/smth/another1/another2/media_files/` and want to redirect `/smth/another1/another2/new_media_files/` then should i use static phrase: `/smth/another1/another2`? but if parent folders are dynamic, and i only know, that `new_media_files` resides same-where is  `media_files` ..

Comment: That'll be pretty tricky and not that simple enough to answer in a comment. If you post a new question then I can try to provide you longer answer.

Comment: i cant open second topic on the same problem, i thought it will be good, if you could provide that answer in your "accepted" answer...

Comment: if i could, i would have rated your answer 10 times! thanks!